# Sprite does not rotate in onManagedUpdate function

Tags: android, andengine

I have a Sprite in Andengine. When I use first code below, it's working and displaying on scene and rotating. But when I use sprite's onManageUpdate method for detect collision or for anything else, sprite isn't rotating...

```
circleBox = new CircleBox(x, y, resourcesManager.circleBoxRegion, 2, vbom);
```

There is rotate function CircleBox class and is rotating in code above.When I use code below is not rotating why?

```
circleBox = new CircleBox(x, y, resourcesManager.circleBoxRegion, 2, vbom){
                    @Override
                    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
                    {
                        if(player.collidesWith(this)){
                            player.setCurrentTileIndex(8); // olunce duran adam pozistonuna gelsin
                            player.getBody().setTransform(new Vector2(100/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, 
                                                                       400/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT), 0); //1=32

                        }

                    }
                };
```

Comment: Why did you add the cocos2d-iphone and iOS tags? They have no relevance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should call - super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed) in onManagedUpdate() method.